# Hosting a Website or Websites Using Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: web-server, server, web

Say that I have a website that gets approximately 5-10k hits per day, and I want to run a full LAMP Stack and phpMyAdmin to manage the mysql databases. Would 1 Raspberry Pi board suffice to handle this much traffic and storage, or would I need to somehow stack multiple boards together to host a bigger website and ensure that things load smoothly to those who visit it? I thought that I saw another guy who built 8 boards together to server more traffic/visitors for his website. What all should I expect to order in order to getting what I need accomplished? Thanks!

Comment: Run it on a Raspberry Pi 4B and you should be OK.

Comment: Which is better, SSD or HDD?

Comment: "Would 1 Raspberry Pi board suffice to handle this much traffic and **storage**" - Other than requiring storage to install the LAMP stack, phpMyAdmin, and MySQL, you have given no info regarding your storage needs.

Answer (score 1):

> Which is better, SSD or HDD?

Obviously, an SSD drive which has connected to Raspberry Pi 4B's USB 3.0 port. You can also fire up a simple web page and find a virtual system that hits a dozen connections to your site like [this link](http://www.loadtracer.com/).

---

> I thought that I saw another guy who built 8 boards together to server
>   more traffic/visitors for his website.

Of course you can do it with a straightforward procedure. Connect some Raspberry Pis to a local network and they'll answer http/https request. It's referred to as "Clustering". Follow the link below:

[Raspberry Pi Cluster for web server](http://raspberrywebserver.com/raspberrypicluster/raspberry-pi-cluster.html)